# How to active math tag on mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I downloaded mediawiki in order to use dump of wikipedia.

But I have a problem when some articles have formulas.
i follow instruction to activate Tex in Mediawiki

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Math
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Texvc
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Enable_TeX

But the main thing I don't understand is to compile Texvc.I don't know what does it mean.Any help? How to run Texvc?

Answer (score 1):

Texvc is included with the [Math extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMath), which I guess you have already downloaded.

Open a terminal window and move to the folder `extensions/Math/math` under your MediaWiki installation. On most operating systems you should now be able to type `make` and hit <enter>. If that doesn't work, try `gmake`. If you still have no success, please tell us what operating system you are using.

You will also have to run the [update.php script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUpdate.php) for things to start work.

Comment: Hi, tank for your reply.In the math directory when I type "make" it doesnt work.When i also type "gmake" it doesnt work also.I'm on windows 7.

Comment: Ok, if you are on Windows you will probably have to download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or something similar, that gives you the make command. I have never used it myself, so I can't really walk you through it.